# how can i install the plugin cordova-plugin-iosrtc on a ionic capacitor project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor, webrtc-ios

I am trying to use getUserMedia to get the stream of the camera.
For that I understood, it is impossible because this function is not yet implemented in ios 14.4 or at least not authorized.(error not allowed)

So I saw that the only way to get the stream is to use this cordova plugin below:
https://github.com/cordova-rtc/cordova-plugin-iosrtc

My problem is when i install it: npm i cordova-plugin-iosrtc

i get an error when i build on ios:

If anyone managed to install it that would be great to help me out.
Thank you.

> ⚠️  ld: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'WebRTC'
>
> ❌  Undefined symbols for architecture arm64
>
> > Symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_RTCMediaConstraints
> > Referenced from: objc-class-ref in PluginRTCPeerConnectionConstraints.o
>
> ❌  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

If someone has succeeded to install it, it would be great to help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the solution.
the iosrtc plugins works with capacitor with this part in your podfile :

```
def disable_bitcode_for_target(target)
  target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'

    remove_cflags_matching(config.build_settings, ['-fembed-bitcode', '-fembed-bitcode-marker'])
  end
end

def remove_cflags_matching(build_settings, cflags)
  existing_cflags = build_settings['OTHER_CFLAGS']

  removed_cflags = []
  if !existing_cflags.nil?
    cflags.each do |cflag|
      existing_cflags.delete_if { |existing_cflag| existing_cflag == cflag && removed_cflags << cflag }
    end
  end

  if removed_cflags.length > 0
    build_settings['OTHER_CFLAGS'] = existing_cflags
  end
end



post_install do |installer|
  project_name = Dir.glob("*.xcodeproj").first
  project = Xcodeproj::Project.open(project_name)
  project.targets.each do |target|
    disable_bitcode_for_target(target)
  end
  project.save

  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    disable_bitcode_for_target(target)
  end

  installer.pods_project.save
end
```

If that can help someone :)